# How do I use ffmpeg to create an audio-synced cut from a single file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, editing, mp4box

I have 1 large file (lets call it test.mp4), and I'd like to create a new file (out.mp4) that takes 3 segments that are 1 second apart:

`Seg1: 00:01:00 - 00:02:00
Seg2: 00:03:00 - 00:04:00
Seg3: 00:06:00 - 00:07:00`

And merge them into out.mp4

I've tried various concat filters, or using the textfile.txt with instructions in it:

`file file-1.wav
duration 20.0`

But various methods produce glitchy video with the x264 codec (green artifacts, choppy out-of-sync audio)

Cutting each segment into its own file and then merging is not applicable because that approach would produce thousands of files and seems quite slow processing wise.

Does anyone have thoughts on how this can be done properly with ffmpeg? Is there an alternative API/CLI tool I could use thats known to work better for these cases?

Comment: Is re-encoding fine?

Comment: I'll take it if its the only option yes